# Cout ничего не выводит

Tags: c++

Часто сталкиваюсь с проблемой того, что `cout`, ничего не выводит, и иногда вообще программа перестаёт выполнятся и завершается без каких-либо ошибок. Вот пример подобного кода:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *f(){
    int arr[3]{1,2,3};
    return arr;
}

int main(){
    int* x = f();
    cout<<x[0];
}
```

При запуске, ошибок нет, и вывода тоже нет. В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Ну, как минимум, у вас UB — возврат указателя на локальную переменную. А UB на то и U, что ничего сказать нельзя :)

Comment: @Harry, Что такое UB?

Comment: @Harry я вынес `int arr[3]{1,2,3};` за скобки перед `int *f`, и всё тоже самое

Comment: Как видите, https://ideone.com/xbup09 — честно выведена 1.

Comment: UB — Undefined behavior — [неопределенное поведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная ошибка возникает из-за передачи указателя на *локальную* переменную, для решения достаточно сделать её глобальной.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr[3]{1,2,3};

int *f(){
    return arr;
}

int main(){
    int* x = f();
    cout<<x[0];
}
```

Вывод: 1